# Tag cleanup: Delete / merge [function] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-cleanup-request

[function](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/function) has no description, but it has cc 130 questions.

In most of the cases it's used as synonym of [worksheet-function](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function) (with or without it), and sometimes referring to functions in scripts or programming languages.

I don't think this tag adds to the value of the questions. When it's used as synonym of [worksheet-function](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function) without it, then it should be replaced, other cases deleted.

Comment: Let's focus on the non-spreadsheet questions first and then we'll just merge the rest into worksheet-function

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/function+-microsoft-excel+-microsoft-excel-2010+-microsoft-excel-2007+-microsoft-excel-2013+-microsoft-excel-2003+-microsoft-excel-2011+-microsoft-excel-2016+-microsoft-excel-2008+-microsoft-excel-2002+-microsoft-excel-2000